# UIDatePicker 15 Minute Increments Swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

In `swift`, I'm wondering how I would use my `UIDatePicker` to select 15 minute increments. So instead of having hours with 60 minutes, I only want to be able to select 00 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes, and 45 minutes.

Here is my current implementation

```
var schedulePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

schedulePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    schedulePicker.addTarget(self, action: "handleSchedulePicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    textField9.inputView = schedulePicker

....
func handleSchedulePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM/dd/yy hh:mm a"
    textField9.text = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date))"
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Set `shedulePicker.minuteInterval = 15`

I found the answer here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/minuteInterval

It's always good to take a look at documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set on the attributes inspector
In the "Interval"

[image: Interval]