# SwiftUI - .hourAndMinute showing only "00" and "30' minutes

Tags: swift, swiftui, datetimepicker

I hope my title is self explanatory enough. I have an hours and minutes time picker, where every minute is shown individually. What I want is to only show the "00" and "30" minutes. Is this achievable?

The code I use for the time picker:

```
DatePicker("", selection: $selectedStartHour, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
    .datePickerStyle(CompactDatePickerStyle())
    .labelsHidden()
    .clipped()
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot do that with pure SwiftUI. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60376694/datepicker-using-time-interval-in-swiftui/71594491#71594491

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment posted is wrong. You can of course do this with a one line piece of code:

```
UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 30
```

The issue is that now all of your time pickers throughout your entire app will be in 30 minute increments. To alleviate this, you use .onAppear and .onDisappear as follows:

```
.onAppear {
    UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 30
}

.onDisappear {
    UIDatePicker.appearance().minuteInterval = 1
}
```

Now, when your view appears the picker will be set to 30 minute increments. When the view disappears, it will be set back to the default of 1 minute increments.

Now you can easily control what time increment is displayed on a per view basis.

Comment: Late reply, but thank you so much! There came a time where I needed a 30 min time interval again, and I saw your answer. Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: How would I apply "60 minute" intervals just showing 00 for the minute "field"?

Comment: From the code: "interval must be evenly divided into 60. default is 1. min is 1, max is 30"